# Error Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined in discord.js

Tags: caching, discord.js

I tried changing the `client.channels` to `client.channel` `client.channelId` still no luck trying to figure this one out for quite some time please help. Am using discord.js v13.1.0 btw

```
const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
    const appStart = await message.author.send({ content: questions[collectCounter++] });
    const channel = appStart.channel;
    const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(filter);

    collector.on("collect", () => {
        if (collectCounter < questions.length){
            channel.send(quesstions[collectCounter++]);
        } else {
            channel.send("Your profile has been succesfully updated")
            Collector.stop("fulfilled"); 
        }
    });
    const femalechannel = client.channels.cache.get("881098900600152084"); 
    const malechannel = client.channels.cache.get("881098930711035924");
```

Comment: Your error suggests that your `client.channels` is already undefined. Is your client in the current scope even valid? Make it is sure to get attributes off of it.

Comment: well the client will be in bot Dms so it has to fetch the channel by Id.. how to define the  client here then?

Comment: If the code above is in another file from where `client` was defined or even outside of `client`:s scope, wrap the entire code in a function and pass the `client` object to it as a variable. If this wasn't of help, please provide us with further code/explanation

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but for people who still find this an issue:

Make sure "channels" are defined. Channels are part of a guild, so you would first want to define the guild, then use it. Here is an example:

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('(your guild id)');
const femalechannel = client.guild.channels.cache.get("881098900600152084"); 
const malechannel = client.guild.channels.cache.get("881098930711035924");
```